# HP G62 BIOS Shutting down for overheating with no actual overheating

Tags: laptop, bios, shutdown, overheating

I've got a HP G62 notebook that randomly shuts down blaming overheating.
Well, for me it's very unexpected because there's no heat in the carcass and the temperature measurings are all okay (40ºC ~ 50ºC).
That happens with Win7, Win10 and even Ubuntu (current system).

I'm attaching some images below

[image: Temperature measurings right before the shutdown]

[image: BIOS message after the shutdown]

Comment: Did you try updating the BIOS?

Comment: @John Good idea, I've temporarily installed W10 to a partition in my HD (the update utility is an .exe). But I'm worried about the update. What if the BIOS shutdown during the update?
The utility gives me an option to update from USB drive. It leaves some files in the drive but I don't know how to use them.

Comment: Wait until any updates are done and then update BIOS so that shutdown does not cause any issue.

Answer (score 0):

My HP Laptop had a similar problem.  I used Open Hardware Monitor (openhardwaremonitor.org - an open source tool) to troubleshoot and in fact I always have a tiny screen of CPU temp showing.

In my case there was an accumulation of dust inside the fan ducting. I paid a professional to take it apart and clean it.  My cleaning didn't reach the right spots.  Originally I thought the heat sink compound broke loose, but not so.

Comment: No problems with the cooling. Everything is clean and also, no overheating. The system is beating regular temperature measurements (40ºC ~ 50ºC) even in the shutdown moment.